# Rails: How to save formatted text in text_area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `text_area` tag which allows the user to enter his Bio. When a user is tyoing and if he hits enter or return, a new line starts. But when he saves his input all the text is displayed in one paragraph. I want functionality similar to what stack overflow has.

For example - I hit enter now

**This text appears on a new line***

How can I do this?

```
This is my code in Rails:

<%= form_for :profile do |profile| %>
    <%= profile.text_area :bio %>

<%= f.submit "Save Bio" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try using raw when you are showing code in view. It is used to display content in html format. Like <%= raw @text %>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use text editor for example [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) (to simplify web content creation), and in view try [simpleformat](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) or [raw](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw):

```
<%= simple_format("Here is some basic text...\n...with a line break.") %>
<%= raw("Here is some basic text...<br/>...with a line break.") %>
```

Comment: I wrote about text editor only to simplify web content creation if you will add more opportunity to users ;)

Comment: raw is not safe when data is coming from user's input

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to handle this. When displaying text previously inputed in text area you can:

1. replace newline characters with `<br/>` tags
2. use `<pre>` tag and display text inside that tag
3. split text by newline characters and then wrap each of the chunks into `<p>` tags

When using approach 1 or 3, make sure to pass text through `raw` helper, so that any tags within text are displayed. Be aware though, that user may pass arbitrary html inside the textarea, hence your code may be subject to xss attacks.

Comment: #2 worked perfectly for me with various \n and \r tags in a string.